# Wait till user completes Multiple choice quiz or check form again in jQuery .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, multiple-choice

I'm writing a multiple choice quiz in jQuery that shows a total score at the end and shows a user a message based on the total score. The odd part about it is that there are 2 questions that depending on if the user selects 6a, 6b, or 6c for example, they cannot answer questions 7 or 8 or both.  I coded if/else statements in .change() to block or allow the next questions. The problem is that with adding .change() the scoring does not work (all the questions are not counted to the score variable).

For some reason as soon as the page loads it is counting all the questions before the user even selects any question and I cannot use .change() if I call a function holding it using .click();

How do I have the program check or wait till the user completes the quiz (user doesnt have to answer all questions) and count all the questions answered for scoring and still allow the question using the if else statement in .change() to be used on the fly?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){          

        var score = 0;
        var scoreQ1 = 0;
        var scoreQ2 = 0;
        var scoreQ3 = 0;
        var scoreQ4 = 0;


    //QUESTION 1



                if (jQuery("input#question_1a").is(":checked")) {
                    scoreQ1 = 0;

                } 
                else if (jQuery("input#question_1b").is(":checked")) {
                    scoreQ1 = 1;

                }
                else if (jQuery("input#question_1c").is(":checked")) {
                    scoreQ1 = 2;

                } else if (jQuery("input#question_1d").is(":checked")) {
                    scoreQ1 = 3;



    //FIND HIGHEST NUMBER OF QUESTIONS 1 - 4
    if(scoreQ1 === 3 || scoreQ2 === 3 || scoreQ3 === 3 || scoreQ4 === 3 ){

        score = score + 3;


    }
    else if(scoreQ1 === 2 || scoreQ2 === 2 || scoreQ3 === 2 || scoreQ4 === 2){

        score = score + 2;


    }   
    else if(scoreQ1 === 1 || scoreQ2 === 1 || scoreQ3 === 1 || scoreQ4 === 1){

        score = score + 1;


    }else if(scoreQ1 === 0 || scoreQ2 === 0 || scoreQ3 === 0 || scoreQ4 === 0){

        score = score + 0;


    }else {

        score = score + 0;

    }

    //QUESTION 6 (do not score, choose next question)
    jQuery("input[name=R6]").change(function() 
    {   

                if (jQuery("input#question_6a").is(":checked")) {


                jQuery("input[name=R7]").removeAttr("checked");
                jQuery('input[name=R7]').attr("disabled",true);

                jQuery("input[name=R8]").removeAttr("checked");
                jQuery('input[name=R8]').attr("disabled",true);


            } else if(jQuery("input#question_6b").is(":checked"))

            {


                 jQuery("input[name=R7]").removeAttr("checked");
                 jQuery('input[name=R7]').attr("disabled",false);

                 jQuery("input[name=R8]").removeAttr("checked");
                 jQuery('input[name=R8]').attr("disabled",false);


            } else if(jQuery("input#question_6c").is(":checked")){



                 jQuery("input[name=R7]").removeAttr("checked");
                 jQuery('input[name=R7]').attr("disabled",false);

                 jQuery("input[name=R8]").removeAttr("checked");
                 jQuery('input[name=R8]').attr("disabled",true);

            } 

    })

  //Questions 7 and 8 look like question 1  

        var scoreQ7 = 0;
        var scoreQ8 = 0;
        var scoreQ9 = 0;
        var scoreQ10 = 0;
        var scoreQ11 = 0;




        //QUESTION 7
        if (jQuery("input#question_7a").is(":checked")) {
            scoreQ7 += 1;
        } else if(jQuery("input#question_7b").is(":checked")){

             scoreQ7 += 2;
        } else if(jQuery("input#question_7c").is(":checked")){

             scoreQ7 += 3;

        } else if( jQuery("input[name=R7]:checked").val()==""  ){

            scoreQ7 += 0;
        }







        //QUESTION 8
        if (jQuery("input#question_8a").is(":checked")) {
            scoreQ8 += 1;
        } else if(jQuery("input#question_8b").is(":checked")){

             scoreQ8 += 2;
        } else if(jQuery("input#question_8c").is(":checked")){

             scoreQ8 += 3;

        } else if( jQuery("input[name=R8]:checked").val()==""  ){

            scoreQ8 += 0;
        }



     jQuery("input#Submit1").click(function(){


    //RESULTS
    if( !jQuery("input[name=lastquestion]:checked").val()=="" ){


                if(score <= 5){

                    jQuery( "#container" ).hide();
                    jQuery( "div#divScore" ).html("display some text");



                } else if( (score > 5 )&& (score < 11) ){

                    jQuery( "#container" ).hide();
                    jQuery( "div#divScore" ).html("display some text");

                }

    }

   });
```

Comment: You have written all your counting logic inside `jQuery(document).ready` .That's why as soon as page loads your logic of counting executes. Ideally you should execute this logic on `jQuery("input#Submit1").click`, so that evaluation of score happens after user has selected all his choices

Comment: @Amit.rk3  Thanks for your quick response. If I wrap the code in `jQuery("input#Submit1").click` instead of `jQuery(document).ready`, the problem now becomes that the `.change();` will not work unless the submit button is hit. How do I keep `.change()` working on those particular questions as soon as the page loads and still do what you said by using `jQuery("input#Submit1").click` so I can get the right score total?

Comment: keep `jQuery("input[name=R6]").change` in document.ready, move rest of your counting logic in `jQuery("input#Submit1").click` . General practice is `.click()` or `.change()` should be in document.ready so that all click or change events are initialized at the page load

Comment: @Amit.rk3. Yes!  That was my thought exactly besides putting them in `jQuery(document).ready`. I moved all the `.change()` code functions outside the click function and it works the way I want it. Thanks so much for your help, your first post really got me in the right direction!